# Have pillow installed and yet getting 'ImportError: No module named PIL'

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

Pillow was working fine for me and then I got this error :

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2452, in open  
    % (filename if filename else fp))  
IOError: cannot identify image file 'dataSet/.DS_Store'
```

From answers on SO I got that it is possible I have both PIL and pillow installed and so I uninstalled PIL and installed pillow using easy_install and ever since then I keep getting this error.

```
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

I tried everything.

```
pip install image  
pip install pillow  
pip upgrade pip  
import PIL from Image
```

`pip --version` gives : `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`
`pip freeze | grep Pillow` gives : `Pillow==4.1.0`

The code I'm running is:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image
```

And at line 4 I keep getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "finder.py", line 4, in <module>  
    from PIL import Image  
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

What else can I do to fix the situation? Did I read all the posts related to this topic on SO? Pretty much. And there are MANY posts related to it as well,but please,help me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that You have Installed Pillow for python3.*
`pip install pillow`
Install the right version for python2.7
from here
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/4.0.0

python2.7 version has `cp27` in it's name, download the right wheel file based on your system architecture.
`pip install some-package.whl`
I hope it helps.

Comment: What makes you think the Python 3 version is installed?

Comment: I don't think it was the version 3. I would have to use pip3 for that isn't it? The problem is solved now. Turns out I had to manually delete pillow files and then re-install. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @momo Then what was it? If the issue is Solved.

Comment: @Hugo i just remembered something from the python docs 3.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first error, this is an expected error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2452, in open
% (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file 'dataSet/.DS_Store'
```

You're trying to open a non-image with Pillow, and it's responding by saying it cannot open it. This is correct behaviour.

I guess you're trying to open all the images in a directory, but it's failing on [.DS_Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store), which a a metadata file created by macOS when viewing the contents of the directory. This file won't have existed before you looked in the directory with Finder, hence the code worked. What you need to do is either ignore this file (as you would with Thumbs.db on Windows), be more careful with globbing (eg. make sure only .jpg or .png or such) or handle the IOError with a `try:`/`except IOError:` block.

Comment: Yes, that error is not occurring anymore. Had to skip/filter those files. Thanks!